# Need to redirect only root of domain, not any subdirectories

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I currently have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com[/]? [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com/.+ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://testsite.com [R=302,L]
```

It's not working too well. I need to redirect the root `http://example.com`, with or without a trailing slash, but no subdirectories `http://example.com/sub`, again, with or without a trailing slash, should be redirected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://testsite.com [R=302,L]
```